# See what API calls of a website is making

Tags: api, rest, unix

Is it possible to see what rest calls a page makes when I visit it? Like if I go to google drive, can I see what calls my browser is making to their web servers? If so how? Would something like Wireshark be used in this case? Is there something higher level than that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Chrome <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> then click network. You can view all network traffic or filter it. AJAX requests generally show up under XHR (XmlHttpRequest) unless the website is using JSONP - in that case they would appear under Scripts.

Comment: What about mac?

Comment: but how to know by which function called that ajax call?

Comment: @T.Woody On macOS Option+Command+I should do the job.

Comment: @spkane 5 years ago I asked a question about the hot key in an answer, and it was just a way top open up devtools. I'm rolling with laughter haha

Answer (score 13):

Here is a demonstration on how to obtain the API URL from the ProtonMail pricing page:

1. Navigate to the ProtonMail [pricing page](https://protonmail.com/pricing).
2. Open Chrome DevTools by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, and then select the `Network` tab.
3. Switch to the `Fetch/XHR` option and click on the desired item in the left panel.
4. The `Request URL` can be found in the `Headers` tab.

[image]

Comment: Is it mean its hided if I can't see anything?

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers have some sort of developer console you can use. For example, in Chrome you can open the console with Ctrl-Shift-J, and then select the Network tab. After that, all network requests will be logged so that you can inspect them.